# Using RasPi as WiFi

Tags: hdmi, streaming

I have a projector installed at my ceiling. I cannot easily run a cable from the projector to my computer. Therefore I'd like to be able to stream movies to the projector using the raspi, while still playing the audio via my PC.

Kind of like Airplay or screensharing (chromecast) for mobile phones, but using a Windows PC.

Is there any way to archive this?

Comment: Could this work for you: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/106184/53481 ?